# pfeed with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am trying to integrate [pfeed](https://github.com/parolkar/pfeed) plugin in mongoid. Is there any way to do it? Or is there any gem or plugin similar to pfeed in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the plugin compatible for mongoid. If anyone is having a same problem they can check it out [here](https://github.com/sadiksha/pfeed).